Files copied to an NTFS drive when I am in Linux are disappearing when I open the drive in Windows
I have a drive named D in Windows partition which is formatted as NTFS.
I also have an Ubuntu 22.04 partition. Whenever I copy any file or folder from the Ubuntu partition to the D drive and then when I mount the Windows OS I no longer see this file and folder in the D drive.
Only when I run the chkdsk D: /f I can see the files and folders. Why is this happening all the time? Is this going to cause any kind of disk corruption?

Are you closing the file-system after write?  (ie. ensure all data is written & buffers in RAM sync'd to device whilst on Ubuntu).  Secondly ensure you don't have fastboot or other hibernate used in windows, as windows doesn't re-read the actual directory where fastboot or hibernate is used in order to ensure a faster startup (meaning data written to it by other OSes won't be detected!)

I just mount the drive and drag and drop to the drive, this is what I usually do. Closing the file-system i did not understand you completely there, but i wait for the entire copy loading to finish before i reboot if that is what you meant.

How do i check for the fastboot or hibernate setting that you mentioned?

fastboot is a feature provided with modern windows; when updates are applied a new fastboot-hibernate file is created and instead of a cold (and thus slow) boot, the system resumes from that saved state.  You disable that feature in windows forcing a cold boot (where your disk is actually read!), and just don't tell your windows to hibernate before booting your Ubuntu.  I rarely use windows, and thus have the settings off by default; and wouldn't be good at advising you in windows settings. fastboot includes caching of parts of disk at upgrade time, thus changes aren't seen

Got it, regarding the mounting part, Should i copy the folders/files via some command rather than drag and drop for the files to be completely copied without any problems?

I doubt using a command (instead of copy/paste in GUI) would make any difference... my first comment was more about ensuring you flushed buffers to persistent/physical storage and didn't have changes stuck in RAM that weren't flushed due to your ejection of device instead of forcing sync first (ie. preventing unclean eject).  You can man sync to get more details if helpful, but doing it via GUI or command I'd expect to be equal.

I mean I unmount via the GUI and it was not throwing any errors after the copy was done, and also when I run the ckdsk command windows i can see all the file in windows. very strange

The chkdsk in windows making them appear implies to me you're not having windows actually read the disk until chkdsk is performed, as chkdsk doesn't used cached data in fastboot/hibernate file BUT actually forces a read from disk/partition directly...  The chkdsk in my view confirms what I describe, however that is still my opinion/view which maybe incomplete (being limited to details you provided in question, and me not knowing how you use your system)  fastboot wasn't intended to be used in dual-boot operations; microsoft warned that when first released!

"On computers which can be dual-booted into Windows or Linux, Windows has to be fully shut down before booting into Linux, otherwise the NTFS file systems on internal disks may be left in an inconsistent state and changes made by Linux may be ignored by Windows." ... Please see Helpful technical information

To ensure that changes to a disk (i.e. removable filesystem)
has been completed you MUST "Eject" the media (windows terms).

Note: "fastboot" and "hibernation" features are a hindrance here, as these BYPASS this, at least on Windows; leaving disk writes in an half finished state - unknown to other OS:es.
Also note that you have to get the "the disk has been safely ejected" (or similar text) just after the click - if that doesn't appear, there is some software still attached to the "disk" - i.e having an open file, or File explorer displaying the content; unless you see this text, Eject has not been done.

In Linux terms "Eject" is equal to "unmount" as done by e.g. udisksctl
$ lsblk -ape7
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/sda           8:0    0  7,3T  0 disk 
└─/dev/sda1        8:1    0  7,3T  0 part /media/hannu/Data8
...

$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sda1 
Unmounted /dev/sda1.

$ lsblk -ape7
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/sda           8:0    0  7,3T  0 disk 
└─/dev/sda1        8:1    0  7,3T  0 part 
...

OR by clicking the "Eject button" in Nautilus (Files, Ubuntu File explorer);
or 'unmount' in any other relevant software: (gnome-)Disks, GPartEd and so on.
More options:
$ udisksctl --help and
$ lsblk --help
besides the man pages -> $ man <programname> 

I did "eject button" after the file transfer was done, and still facing this issue

Edited the A, new text.
